# 'must' and 'should' combined in bool query not working

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, lucene

while searching `galaxy mobiles` in elasticsearch.
It creates a query like below as `galaxy` should be searched in `mobiles` category.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
        }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "type": "phrase"
            }
        }],
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "category": "mobiles"
            }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

Only `must` condition is working , `should` condition is not working.
Is there any issue in the above query.?

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  What are you expecting?

Comment: I want products in mobile category with galaxy in title or other fields. But it is giving me only mobiles category

Answer (score 0):

If should and must on the same level, than should does not have any impact. So possible this is what you want:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "operator": "and"
            }
           }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
           }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "type": "phrase"
            }
          }]
         }},
       "must": {
            "term": {
                "category": "mobiles"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution like this below. It is working fine.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "galaxy",
                        "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }, {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "galaxy",
                        "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                        "type": "phrase_prefix"
                    }
                }, {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "galaxy",
                        "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "category": "mobiles"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) elastic search documentation, you will see the following:

> should
>
> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. In a
>   boolean query with no must or filter clauses, one or more should
>   clauses must match a document. The minimum number of should clauses to
>   match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.

So the correct query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
        }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "galaxy",
                "fields": ["title", "product_specs", "category", "brand", "os"],
                "type": "phrase"
            }
        }],
        "minimum_should_match":1,
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "category": "mobiles"
            }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I added the "minimum_should_match":1